# Performing union with three queries - SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

In my project setup querying is being done based on the SQLAlchemy.

As per my previous requirements I have done the union with two queries.

Now I need to do Union with three queries.

Code is as follows:

```
query1 = query1.filter(model.name == "in-addr.arpa.")
query2 = query2.filter(model.tenant_id.in_(tenant_ids))
query = query1.union(query2)
```

Now Here I need to add one more query as follows:

```
query3 = query3.filter(model.tenant_id == context.tenant_id)
```

So I need to perform Union with all the three queries.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The solution is following:

```
query1 = query1.filter(model.name == "in-addr.arpa.")
query2 = query2.filter(model.tenant_id.in_(tenant_ids))
query3 = query3.filter(model.tenant_id == context.tenant_id)
query = query1.union(query2,query3)
```

Comment: Using the method union in SQLalchemy 1.4 gives me `TypeError: union() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`. For more than 2 queries I would use the function union instead, see my answer.

Answer (score 13):

This is how I did this in SQLAlchemy 1.3

```
from sqlalchemy import union

query1 = query1.filter(model.name == "in-addr.arpa.")
query2 = query2.filter(model.tenant_id.in_(tenant_ids))
query3 = query3.filter(model.tenant_id == context.tenant_id)

all_queries = [query1, query2, query3]
golden_set = union(*all_queries)
```

The change here is that the union method accepts a list of SQLAlchemy selectables.

Comment: I am using - from sqlalchemy.sql import union. The above solution failed for me with error - TypeError: 'CompoundSelect' object is not iterable

Comment: @skyfail Weird, this is working for me. How many objects do you have in your dict? Can you show the contents of each? Is each a select object? What version of SQLAlchemy are you on?

Comment: n<=5 select items in list. Each select is looking at the same table and filtering on some columns. SQLAlchemy==1.1.15

Comment: Just wondering, if you do this with just two tables, does it work? Also, your queries are actually select objects and not string SELECT statements, right?

Comment: It's worth noting here that the `union()` method returns a CompoundSelect object, so you can't execute the query with `all()` like you would with a Query object. You have to do `session.execute(golden_set)`

Answer (score 1):

In SQLAlchemy 1.4 you will need to use the function union and pass the queries as positional arguments instead of a list.

```
from sqlalchemy import union

query1 = query1.filter(model.name == "in-addr.arpa.")
query2 = query2.filter(model.tenant_id.in_(tenant_ids))
query3 = query3.filter(model.tenant_id == context.tenant_id)

query = union(query1, query2, query3)
```